# Need to redirect On /clinics directory by unique word

Tags: .htaccess

I need redirect url like http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/clinics/england/bedfordshire/luton to http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/clinics can anyone give me a better solution to redirect..There is 1000's url like this.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this `RedirectMatch` rule in your root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(clinics)/.+$ /$1
```

> How can i redirect it to clinics/CA/england/ to the /clinics

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/(clinics)/CA/england/ /$1
```

Comment: Yes you are right but i did not want to redirect http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/clinics.

Comment: /clinics no need to redirection but only url like http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/clinics/england/bedfordshire/luton need to redirect on http://www.sportsinjuryclinic.net/clinics

Comment: If that's the case use: `RedirectMatch 301 ^/(clinics)/england /$1`

Comment: Yes Its Working perfect! How can i redirect it to  clinics/CA/england/ to the /clinics

Comment: can we use RedirectMatch 301 ^/(clinics)/(CA)/england /$1